# SQL Server delete nowait doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I've got 3 tables:

Schema:
[image]

For example, I have data like:

```
1> select id, iddep, idservice from transactions where id = 22
2> go
 id          iddep       idservice
 ----------- ----------- -----------
          22           6          12
```

I run the following queries, and result is predictable:

First connection queries:

```
1> begin tran
2> go
1> select id from transactions with (updlock) where id = 22
2> go
 id
 -----------
          22
```

Second connection queries:

```
1> begin tran
2> go
1> delete from transactions with (nowait) where id = 22
2> go
SQL Server Error: 1222 Lock request time out period exceeded
```

This is normal behavior for NOWAIT hint, what is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)

But! If I do the following queries, result is very strange!

First connection queries are the same as in the first example:

```
1> begin tran
2> go
1> select id from transactions with (updlock) where id = 22
2> go
 id
 -----------
          22
```

Second connection queries:

```
1> begin tran
2> go
1> delete from services with (nowait) where id = 12
2> go
```

I just try to delete parent row and.. Nothing happens! It just waits for the row to release in despite of `nowait` hint. And when I release that row, parent row deletes.

So, why I don't just receive the 1222 error, as in the first example?

Comment: In the second example, you are deleting a different row. Is this a typo? If not, Then the chances are that SQL is taking a row level lock for each, not a table level, hence they don't block each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right there in the page you link to, but maybe not obvious. [`NOWAIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

> Instructs the Database Engine to return a message as soon as a lock is encountered on **the table**. `NOWAIT` is equivalent to specifying `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0` for a specific table.

**Emphasis added**

In the final case in your question, the `DELETE` isn't waiting for a lock on `services` (**the table**) - it's waiting for a lock on `transactions` so that it can verify that the foreign key constraint will not be violated.

And the same quote points out the way to solve it: Specify [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx) on your second connection, and it won't wait for locks on *any* table.